# fetching null value in php framework, laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I need laravel query builder to fetch `''` as `gdate` to do union of another query.

example below:

```
$unionquery = DB::table('mt_task_category')
->whereIn('role_id', [1])
->select('null as gdate', 'null as user_id', 
         'category_id', 'category_name', 
         'null AS timeSum', 'null AS gdfullname', 
         'null AS id', 'null AS pmfullname', 'null AS role_name');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

```
$unionquery = DB::table('mt_task_category')
                ->select(DB::raw('null AS gdate', 'null AS user_id', 
                        'category_id', 'category_name', 
                        'null AS timeSum' , 'null AS gdfullname', 
                        'null AS id', 'null AS pmfullname', 
                        'null AS role_name'));
                ->whereIn('role_id', [1])
                ->get();
```